# Cannot update stateful object on onChange in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, onchange, ant-design-pro

I am trying to update my object when getting number input. I can update "total" ( which I calculate based on input number ) but I cannot assign same input number to another object property --> ( quantity )
When I console log everything I get correct "total" but quantity remains 0.

```
    <Form.Item label="Quantity">
        <InputNumber onChange={handleAmount} />
</Form.Item>
```

//////////////////////////////

```
 const handleAmount = (amount) => {
    
            setOrderlist ({...orderlist, total : orderlist.price*amount});
            setOrderlist ({...orderlist, quantity: amount});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your state, do it in one go instead

```
setOrderlist ({...orderlist, total: orderlist.price*amount, quantity: amount}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call `setOrderList` twice.

You can just do a single:

```
const handleAmount = (amount) => { 
  setOrderList({ ...orderList, total: orderList.price * amount, quantity: amount })
}
```